# xforms bind in repeat with two instances

Tags: xslt, xforms

I have a requirement where i have two instances:
**instance1:**

```
<some >
<Element12/>
<Element123/>
<example>
    <tree id="qw" show="true">
        <label>This tree</label>
    </tree>
    <tree id="as" show="true">
        <label>This is tree</label>
    </tree>
</example>
```

**instance2:**

```
<data>
<SomeElement/>
<example>
    <tree id="qw" show="true">
        <label>This tree</label>
    </tree>
    <tree id="as" show="true">
        <label>This is tree</label>
    </tree>
</example></data>
```

depending on the inputs i will submit one instance.
There are set of question with yes and no radio buttons.
These inputs i have to bind to both the instances.
Currently i have binded one of the instance to the radio button

```
  <xf:repeat id="fl" nodeset="instance('instance1')/some/example/tree">
    <xf:select1 ref="@show" >
      <xf:label><xf:output ref="../label"  /></xf:label>
      <xf:item>
        <xf:label>yes</xf:label>
        <xf:value>true</xf:value>
      </xf:item>
      <xf:item>
        <xf:label>No</xf:label>
        <xf:value>false</xf:value>
      </xf:item>
    </xf:select1>
  </xf:repeat>
```

That instance is working fine.
For another instance i am trying to bind like this:

```
<xf:repeat nodeset="instance('instance2')/example/tree">
        <xf:bind ref="@show" calculate="instance('instance1')/some/example/tree/@show"/>
    </xf:repeat>
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by using `xforms insert` while doing the submission i have copied the element of first instance to the second instance:

```
<xf:insert nodeset="instance('instance2')/example" origin="instance('instance1')/some/example" />
```

This copied the whole example element from the binded instance to the unbinded.